# How much does the View Binding impact on the size of the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, findviewbyid, android-viewbinding

The View Binding, as specified by the documentation, generates a Binding class for each XML element, so as to facilitate access and inspection, as well as lighten the time load given by `findViewById`.

While the `findViewById` acts through a more expensive associative search, the Binding should access "directly" the resource searched for by id thanks to the mapping.

Does this temporal lightening correspond to a spatial weighting?

Having a large project fully developed using the classic `findViewById`, the conversion to the Binding cannot be done "in the dark" and we cannot even experiment and risk compromising the project.

So..

How much does the app size increase given the Binding?
How much impact the classes generated by the Binding on the dimensions?

Comment: Asking "how much larger will my app be with view binding?" Is an impossible question to answer, there are too many considerations : How many bindings, how many Fragements/Activities, Proguard rules, do you use apk, aab, instant app etc. You don't have to compromise a project by refactoring - that is why you should have source control, CI & QA to mitigate this. How would you ever develop any new features otherwise if changing anything could compromise a project.  You should consider compile time safety for bindings - thats probably the highest consideration over an app being a few kb larger.

Comment: My question was not quantitative, but qualitative. So, for example, for an average project is it possible for the app size to double, triple, quadruple? Or can binding classesmake the app size <10% increase? That was the sense of my question. However your comment provides a great explanation and many parameters to think about. Thank you!